# Postgres search missing date with generate_series

Tags: postgresql, date, generate-series

I have a table in my Postgres database which has a column of `date`s. I want to search which of those dates are missing, for example:

```
        date
|2016-11-09 18:00:00|
|2016-11-09 19:00:00|
|2016-11-09 20:00:00|
|2016-11-09 22:00:00|
|2016-11-09 23:00:00|
```

Here `2016-11-09 21:00:00` is missing. I want to make a query with `generate_series` that returns the date which is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t
   FROM generate_series(
           TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2016-11-09 18:00:00',
           TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2016-11-09 23:00:00',
           INTERVAL '1 hour'
        ) t
EXCEPT
SELECT tscol
   FROM mytable;
```

Comment: @Laurenz Albe If my table is having 2016-11-09 18:30:00  i would like to remove 2016-11-09 18:00:00 from my generate series. how do i query?

Comment: @ShamseerPC You should ask a new question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe please find the new question link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846107/postgres-search-available-time-slots-with-generate-series