# Postgres search available time slots with generate_series

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in my postgres database which has a column of dates. I want to search which of those dates is missing - for example:

```
date
2016-11-09 18:30:00
2016-11-09 19:00:00
2016-11-09 20:15:00
2016-11-09 22:20:00
2016-11-09 23:00:00
```

Here, `|2016-11-09 21:00:00|` is missing. After sorting my generated series if my table has an entry between two slots (slot of 1 hr interval) i need to remove that.

I want to make a query with `generate_series` that returns me the date which is missing. Is this possible?.

sample query that i used to generate series.

```
    SELECT t
    FROM generate_series(
       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2016-11-09 18:00:00',
       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2016-11-09 23:00:00',
       INTERVAL '1 hour'
    ) t
    EXCEPT
    SELECT tscol
    FROM mytable;
```

But this query is not removing 2016-11-09 18:30:00,2016-11-09 20:15:00 etc. cuz i used except.

Comment: What do you mean by 'missing'?  Do you have a list of dates that should be there?  Or is there a certain interval that must be respected?

Comment: What defines a "slot"?

Comment: @Dave yes 1 hr interval

Comment: You need `generate_series()` (and maybe `min()` and `max()` and `date_trunc()` and  `NOT EXISTS(...)`

Comment: @wildplasser i updated my question with sample query can you please help wth query ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a gaps-and-island problem. You just want to find the 1 hour intervals for which no record exist in the table.

`EXCEPT` does not work here because it does equality comparison, while you want to check if a record exists or not *within* a range.

A typical solution for this is to use a left join antipattern:

```
select dt
from generate_series(
    timestamp with time zone '2016-11-09 18:00:00',
    timestamp with time zone '2016-11-09 23:00:00',
    interval '1 hour'
) d(dt)
left join mytable t
    on t.tscol >= dt and t.tscol < dt + interval '1 hour'
where t.tscol is null
```

You can also use `not exists`:

```
select dt
from generate_series(
    timestamp with time zone '2016-11-09 18:00:00',
    timestamp with time zone '2016-11-09 23:00:00',
    interval '1 hour'
) d(dt)
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t
    where t.tscol >= dt and t.tscol < dt + interval '1 hour'
)
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5f4da9f8257b61d9995d7cd3d8532055)**, both queries return:

```
| dt                     |
| :--------------------- |
| 2016-11-09 21:00:00+00 |
```